# When using a selector in Angular, how can I set the size the component displays as?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, selector

I'm using a selector, `<component-selector></component-selector>` to display the contents of the component in a page, but it is curently displaying too large, cutting off the right side of the contents of the component, I have tried this:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;">
  <component-selector></component-selector>
</div>
```

as I want it to fill the whole page, but not display as larger than the page, but this isn't working. How can I set this div so the component take up the whole page, but isn't larger/getting cut off?

Comment: can you upload a stackblitz with your whole code, this issue is not visible (at least for me) just with the code you posted

Comment: I would recommend looking into flexbox, simply let it flex to take up available space.

Comment: The div as you've used it isn't part of the component. It should be part of a parent component or your overall layout. It's hard to answer without context, but this is really not an Angular question (unless you're learning how to include CSS, but that's well documented).

Comment: Did you try setting the style on the component, without using the outer `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two divs as block Outer and Inner One, In case you are using selector so there you are using some html code in your selector html code set `width:"100%"` and in out div as `max-width:"1170px"`.

So write like this:

```
<div style="width:100%"> // in selector html code
```

and

```
<div style="width:1170px">// in your Outer container as you are using
```

So the final code looks like this

```
<div style="width:1170px; margin: 0px 15px; display:inline-block">
<selector></selector> // here in this html file set width as 100%
</div>
```

In case if you want solution will code in stackblitz and share you the link
but i know you can do by this reference.